# Using .map in nativescript with angular2

Tags: angular, nativescript

Trying to use http module from angular2 in nativescript, but I am getting this error:

```
file:///app/tns_modules/angular2/src/platform/serv
er/parse5_adapter.js:55:75: EXCEPTION: TypeError: _this.http.request(address, options)
                            .map is not a function. (In '_this.http.request(address, options)
```

This is working in the browser and also including in both places the rxjs map module

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

If I remove this from the browser I am getting the same message. But with nativescript even if I add it, it doesnt work...

What can be wrong here? Is there any working example using the http module?

Comment: Are you using the angular http module?

Comment: Seemingly there is an issue with IOS: `https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/38`. But yes I was using http module.

Comment: That's interesting, I've been using the http module from angular2 and it works just fine on iOS. What version of angular2 and nativescript-angular framework are you using?